# How does one define transcendental numbers (such as Pi) in theory of general recursive functions

Tags: turing-machines, computability, lambda-calculus, generating-functions

On a **turing machine** and in the **lambda calculus** one can define transcendental numbers such as Pi, the golden ratio, etc.
These are computatible functions with 0-arity that never terminate.
In the theory of **general recursive functions** (which also defines the same class of functions as **turing machines** and **lambda calculus**) the output is always a natural number N, or undefined.
How does one define transcendental numbers in the theory of **general recursive functions** (mathematical functions defined by Gödel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only interested in transcendental (or at least only irrational) numbers, you can safely identify the number $x$ with the function $d_x : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that on input $n$ outputs the $n$-th digit of the decimal expansion of $x$.

If you want all real numbers, that does not lead to a satisfactory theory of computation. A suitable way to handle reals there is to let a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ code a real number $x$ if $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ |\nu(f(n)) - x| < 2^{-n}$$ where $\nu : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is some standard bijection. This means that there are many functions coding the same real, but that is unavoidable.

Comment: I understand that its not possible to define ALL reals [uncountable], and your answer really hits it on the head for me - Thank you.

Comment: @RFV Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't updated my profile in years.